# What is the best way to store data in a Page Object Model Framework

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datastore, pageobjects

Im building an automation framework in selenium using the Page Object Design Pattern.
Following are some of the data that Im using and where i have stored them

1. PageObjects (xpath, id etc) - In the Page Classes itself
   [image]
2. Configuration Data (wait-times, browser type , the URL etc) - In a properties file.
   [image]
3. Other data - In a class as static variables.
   [image]

Once the framework starts growing it would be hard to store all the data it would be hard to organize the data. I did a some research on how others have implemented the way they store data in their framework. Here is what I found out,

1. Storing data (mostly page objects) in classes itself
2. Storing data in JSON
   [image]
3. And some even suggested storing data in a database so that it would reduce reading times

Since there are lot of options out there, I thought of getting some feedback on what is the best way to store data and how everyone else has stored there data.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

JSON or Any temp data storage is the best option as it is a framework and the purpose of it is to reuse for different projects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with the way you have stored your data.

1. Locators (by POM definition) should be stored in the page objects themselves.
2. Config data can be stored in some sort of config file... whatever you find convenient. You can use plain text, JSON, XML, etc. We use XML but that really comes down to personal preference.
3. I think this is fine also.

The framework doesn't really grow, the automation suite does. As long as you keep the data stored in the 3 places above consistently, I think you should be fine. The only issue I've run into with this approach is that sometimes certain pages have a LOT of functionality on them so the page objects grow quite large. In those cases, we found a way to divide the page into smaller chunks, e.g. one page had 22 tabs, each consisting of a different panel. In that case, we broke the page object into 22 different class files to keep the size more manageable and then hooked them all back into the main page as properties, e.g. `mainPage.Panel1.someMethodOnPanel1();`

Answer (score -1):

I advice using Interfaces for each device type to store multiple type selectors, example:

```
import static org.openqa.selenium.By.cssSelector;
import static org.openqa.selenium.By.linkText;
import static org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath;

public interface DesktopMainPageSelector {
    By FIRST_ELEMENT = cssSelector("selector_here");
    By SECOND_ELEMENT = xpath("selector_here");
    By THIRD_ELEMENT = id("selector_here");
}
```

than, just implement these selectors from whatever you need them.

You can also use enums with for a more complex structure.

I found this as best solution, because its easy to manage large numbers of selectors

Comment: I personally don't think this is a good best-practice solution.  All these fields are effectively `public static final`, which has drawbacks.  Encapsulation is one, you lose the ability to hide these fields from other classes that shouldn't need to know about them.  Them all being static means they represent global state, which they aren't, they're attributes of specific pages.  And finally, this looks like a poor mans mixins, which could introduce bugs later on.  If you have many of these, and two of them define the same member name, you'll run into problems if you implement both.

Comment: I think simply re-approaching this same solution using composition instead of inheritance would turn this into a solid approach.  Instead of a page implementing an interface to gain functionality, assign a container object containing locators to an instance field to be used.  This ensures that collections of these locators remain in an isolated and controllable scope, keeps global state to a minimum, and by pattern encourages OOP design which aligns with a good page object implementation.

Comment: i disagree, the point is that actually i will use these selectors in other flows (class for pages is bad imho). Let me explain better. As building a test framework (not simple tests), i decided to use this system to build different flows, so having them inside an interface, they can be easily accessible from whenever i need them, each flow is encapsulated and delegated according to properties passed from high level, so the result is: one test which will run for mobile/desktop/tablet/whatever, at the end, we i got complex framework with dumb simple tests methods so non programmers can use.